# Scala Form email type mismatched in my models

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to decipher how to use forms in the Play Framework. The documentation seems limited, and I'm struggling to map a Form to the case class I have defined in my models package.

In controllers.Contact:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._ 
import play.api.data._

import play.api.data.Forms._
import play.api.data.validation.Constraints._

import models.ContactForm

object Contact extends Controller {

/**
 * contactForm binding to models.ContactForm
 */
val contactForm = Form[ContactForm](
    mapping(
        "Name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "Email" -> email,
        "Message" -> text
    )
)(ContactForm.apply)(ContactForm.unapply)

/**
 * Display the contact form.
 * @return Action
 */
def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.contact())
}

/**
 * Send an email.
 * 
 */
def email = TODO

}
```

In models.ContactForm

```
package models

import play.api.data.Forms._

case class ContactForm(
    Name: String,
    Email: email,
    Message: Option[String]
)
```

What I can't understand is why, if the type of parameter `Email` is `email` in my models case class, the symbol cannot be resolved, but if I change it to `String`, it's a type mismatch (especially since `email` just maps to a `String` via regex)

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here. First, `email` is not a type, it's just an instance of `Mapping` used for validation, mapped to `String`. Second, if you want to map `message` to `Option[String]`, then `text` must be `optional(text)`. The difference between `text` and `nonEmptyText` is that `text` will allow empty strings, but both map to `String`. Lastly, your  `apply` and `unapply` arguments for `mapping` are misplaced. It should look more like this:

```
case class ContactForm(
    name: String,
    email: String,
    message: Option[String]
)

val contactForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "Name" -> nonEmptyText,
        "Email" -> email,
        "Message" -> optional(text)
    )(ContactForm.apply)(ContactForm.unapply)
)
```

It's also a common convention in scala to lowercase your field names (well, camel-case), to help distinguish between a type and a value.

**Edit:**

It was hard to tell with all of the other errors previously, but the type mismatch error is being caused by your `email` controller function.

`"Email" -> email` is actually a tuple. `(String, Mapping[String])`, to be exact. `email` is really a function returning `Mapping[String]` within the `play.api.data.Forms` object. However, the `email` function you've defined is causing a namespace conflict, and the scala compiler is trying to use the one in the scope of the controller, which has type `Action`.

If you explicitly use `"Email" -> Forms.email`, instead this will solve the type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks LimbSoup! I really appreciate it. I made the adjustment, but I noticed that the type mismatch exists. Does that mean that on the case class, I need to update the email String to mapping[email, String]? I tried using the case class code that you provided, but I'm still showing a mismatch.

Comment: @EricKeyte What is the exact error? My sample compiled just fine for me.

Comment: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])
 required: (String, play.api.data.Mapping[?])

Comment: And what line is triggering that? The case class and form shouldn't be triggering it. It looks more like something in the controller, but not from the code above.

Comment: Line 21: "email" -> email; (The hyphen in the arrow is highlighted red.)

Comment: Sorry maybe that isn't helpful... Form is also underlined in red, saying "cannot resolve method Form.apply". I'm using IDEA.

Comment: Try compiling with activator/sbt.

Comment: I got the same result in activator/sbt. Play 2.3.0, Scala version 2.11.1.

Comment: I decided to try this again, and it looks like `email` is not supported in the mapping. After replacing it with `nonEmptyText`, it compiled.

Comment: @EricKeyte That doesn't make sense. `nonEmptyText` and `email` are both of type `Mapping[String]`. What happens if you try `Forms.email` instead? Perhaps there is some symbol conflict.

Comment: @EricKeyte In fact, I'm sure if it.. as the controller function `def email = TODO` is being resolved. Hence the `(String, play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent])`.  Using `Forms.email` will definitely fix this, and I'll edit my answer to reflect this.